# Finding the number of possible combinations for polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, permutations

For example, if I have two numbers

$m=\text{max power of each coefficient}$

$n=\text{max sum of the power of the coefficients}$

so for $~m=2~$ and $~n=3~$, the polynomial(which consists of two variables $~x~$ and $~y~$) would look like

$=c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}y+c_{4}x^2+c_{5}y^2 +c_{6}xy+c_{7}xy^2+c_{8}x^2y$

Is there a good way to find the number of terms in the polynomial.

Comment: So, to rephrase, you are looking for the number of non-negative integer solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k \leq n\\0\leq x_i\leq m~~\forall i\end{cases}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my interpretation above is correct, after rephrasing and generalizing further the number of available variables (*and renaming the variables from $x$ and $y$ to instead $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$*) you are trying to count the number of non-negative integer solutions to the system:

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k\leq n\\ 0\leq x_i\leq m~~\forall i\end{cases}$$

If so, then introduce an additional variable, I'll call $y$ equal to $n-x_1-x_2-\dots-x_k$ and you now are working with the system $$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k+y \color{red}{=}n\\0\leq x_i\leq m~~\forall i\\ 0\leq y\end{cases}$$

From there, apply inclusion-exclusion over the events that an $x_i$ exceeded the value of $m$ and use stars-and-bars to calculate each case.

You get as a result a total of:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-i(m+1)+k}{k}$$

Comment: for m=2 and n=3 I am not getting the result of 8(getting 1 instead)?

Comment: @robotlover Thanks., I had a typo apparently, having a minus where I should have had a plus.  That should fix it.

Comment: But in that case how is the (3+2-2*(3))C2=(-1)C(2) evaluated?

Comment: @robotlover In this context, this is the regular binomial coefficient, (*not an extended binomial coefficient*) and so $\binom{a}{b}$ where $a$ is negative is automatically equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It now works.